# Sql Pai e Filhos na Mesma Tabela

Tags: php, sql, informix

Estou com a seguinte questão, tenho uma tabela no banco que não pode ser alterada para facilitar o processo. Nesta tabela tenho registros pais e filhos com a possibilidade de até 8 níveis. Mais ou menos assim, como no esquema abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste exemplo, 123 é código original, que gera o 1015, depois o 1015 se torna origem e gera o 2016 e por ai vai, não sei se ficou claro? Meu problema está em buscar os valores, estou tentando criar um forma de buscar histórico o valor original até consegui algo, porém o usuário que buscar pelo destino e retornar a hierarquia na mesma forma que ele busca 123 e retorna todo o caminho até o 2016.

No meu caso o erro aconteceu quando o usuário tentou buscar o valor 3017 que é no exemplo o destino final, e não estou conseguindo criar um código retornar os valores finais.

Meu código até agora:

```
function get_origem($con,$origem){

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE origem = '$origem'";

   $movimentacao = ifx_query($sql,$con) or die(ifx_errormsg());

   $row = ifx_fetch_row($movimentacao);

   // Aqui insiro os valores em uma tabela temporária e depois listo ela com JOIN com outras tabelas.
   // E chamo a função novamente para pegar o próximo filho.

   get_origem($con,$row['destino']);

}
```

Uso PHP e Informix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi você precisa que a pesquisa retorne toda a árvore, mesmo que o critério seja o item final, como no exemplo 3017.

O problema é que seu código apenas avança para os destinos e nunca testa se existe origem para um determinado ponto. Uma maneira seria adicionar uma função para pesquisar as origens a partir do destino.

Talvez isso funcione:

```
// FUNCAO PARA SIMPLIFICAR A CHAMADA DA PESQUISA DE AMBOS OS CAMINHOS
function get_origem_destino($criterio){

   // codigo para criar a conexao $con

   get_origem($con,$criterio);
   get_destino($con,$criterio);

}


// FUNCAO PARA PESQUISAR ORIGENS A PARTIR DO DESTINO
function get_origem($con,$destino){

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE destino = '$destino'";

   $movimentacao = ifx_query($sql,$con) or die(ifx_errormsg());

   $row = ifx_fetch_row($movimentacao);

   // Aqui insiro os valores em uma tabela temporária e depois listo ela com JOIN com outras tabelas.
   // E chamo a função novamente para pegar o próximo PAI.

   get_origem($con,$row['origem']);

}


// SUA FUNCAO ORIGINAL MAS COM NOME DIFERENTE
// pois está buscando o destino a partir da origem 
function get_destino($con,$origem){

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE origem = '$origem'";

   $movimentacao = ifx_query($sql,$con) or die(ifx_errormsg());

   $row = ifx_fetch_row($movimentacao);

   // Aqui insiro os valores em uma tabela temporária e depois listo ela com JOIN com outras tabelas.
   // E chamo a função novamente para pegar o próximo filho.

   get_origem($con,$row['destino']);

}
```